# Show category list with new posts

Tags: wordpress, categories

I would like to display a list of categories that have new posts in the past x days, without showing the names of posts and without duplicated category names in the list.

For Example:
1. Category B (new post)
2. Category C (new post)
3. Category F (new post)
etc.

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this? I have absolutely no clue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get_posts to get correct orderby and display categories through its loop.

Here is an example:

```
$latest=get_posts(
       array("post_per_page"=>100,
      'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
            'after' => '1 month ago',
        )
    )));

$final_cats=array();

foreach($latest as $lst){
  $postcat = get_the_category( $lst->ID );
  $final_cats[]='<a href="'.get_term_link($postcat[0]->term_id).'">'.$postcat[0]->name.'</a>' ;
}

$final_cats=array_unique($final_cats);
$i=0;
$desired_count=10; //max number of displayed cats.

foreach($final_cats as $fc){
  $i++;
  if ($i>=$desired_count) break;
  echo $i.')'.$fc.' ';
}
```